# Pullback of an epimorphism in the category of Hausdorff spaces

Tags: category-theory, pullback, epimorphisms

Can anyone give me an example of a pullback of an epimorphism which is not an epimorphism, in the category of Hausdorff spaces?

I've been thinking about it but I have no idea.

Comment: By “Hausdorff category”, do you mean the category of Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean

Comment: Well, do you know anything about which maps of Hausdorff spaces are epi? Pullbacks of epis in the full topological category are epi so we need to know how Hausdorff epis are weird.

Comment: Yes, i know that $f:X\to Y$ is epi iff $f[X]$ is dense on $Y$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $D$ a proper dense subset of $X$.
As you said in the comments, the inclusion map $i \colon D \to X$ is an epimorphism in the category of Hausdorff spaces; but if we take $x \in X \setminus D$ and $f \colon \{*\} \to X$ the map sending $*$ to $x$, then
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
f^{-1}[D] @>f>> D \\
@VjVV @VViV \\[-0.8mm]
\{*\} @>>f> X
\end{CD}
$$
is a pullback square in which $j$ (also the inclusion map) is not an epimorphism (since $f^{-1}[D]=\varnothing$).